# Duplicated objects disappear

Tags: objects, error, dupli-groups

I have duplicating the objects in the scene but when I hit play the duplications disappear, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you duplicate objects that have a keyframe animation attached that include keyframes on the location, these duplicated objects will snap to that very same location. You will have to move to each frame that has a keyframe, position the duplicated object and insert/update the keyframe to the correct location.

Comment: right right, I know what you mean, great thanks.